# Execute a command in cmd every X minutes. How?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have these two `.bat` files:

`startserver.bat`:

```
@Echo off
java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.14w21b.jar -d64
```

`backup.bat`:

```
SET COUNTER=0  
:loop  
SET /a COUNTER=%COUNTER%+1  
XCOPY "Lagg3dcraft\*" "c:\Users\Jon\Google Drive\MINECRAFT  
SERVER\Lagg3dcraft(backups)\server_backup_%COUNTER%" /i /s  
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 900000 > NUL  
goto loop
```

1. I want to launch the `backup.bat` file every time I start the `startserver.bat`.
2. I want that in the `startserver.bat` execute this command `/say Server Saved` every X minutes.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score -1):

In startserver.bat you can simply add `start backup.bat` before starting the server.

After that it gets more complicated because the bat file kind of stops after starting the server (waits until it's done with the server, and that is very unconvenient), the easiest way to solve this is probably to get a plugin that can `/say Server Saved` every x minute.

Answer (score -1):

Get a sleeper tool like sleep.exe. One can be downloaded [here](http://www.sleepcmd.com/).

You can use it like this:

```
:loop
... do something ...
sleep 60  ## 60 seconds / 1 min.
goto loop
```

This may be possible as well but you have to enable delayed expansion to have variables expand quickly with `!!`.

```
for /l %%a in (,,) do (
    ... do something ...
    sleep 60
)
```